# I want links inside my div with animated toggle height to be clickable

Tags: javascript, jquery, hyperlink, jquery-animate, height

I have a div that, when clicked, increases in height, and vice versa. Inside the div is an RSS feed catcher. The problem is that when the Div is expanded, and the links on the RSS feeds are clicked, the Div simply collapses rather than following the link.

Here is the code:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#divright").toggle(function(){
$("#divright").animate({
height:640,
borderBottomWidth: "0px"},500);
},function(){
$("#divright").animate({
height:45,
borderBottomWidth: "1px"},500);    
});
});
```

and the link (graphic design news bit)

http://flatpack.site90.com/About%20Flatpack.html

How can i sort it so that I can click the links on the RSS feeds, but also retain the ability to collapse the panel somehow.

Thanks :)

Comment: [event.stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can, break out your toggler from the expanding area.
I would do it like this

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <h2 class="toggler">Toggler</h2>
    <ul>
        <li>News</li>
    </ul>
</div>​


$(".wrapper h2.toggler").click(function(){
    var $ul = $(this).next();
    $ul.toggle("slide");
});​
```

http://jsfiddle.net/wz2Gt/15/

Comment: @ThanGill Thanks for your response. I tried the way you stated but unfortunately couldn't get the RSS catcher to behave properly in the list, but had a think about the concept of separating the toggler from the hidden content and came up with a very simple solution that works well. All I did was change the "#divright" in line 2 to "#divright h2, #divright h1" and changed the "graphic design news" and "click to enlarge" div content to H1 & H2 tags (a technique I borrowed from the code you supplied). Thanks for your help :)